# Means to properly authenticate NIFI users behind an LB that changes cert?

Tags: load-balancing, apache-nifi, aws-application-load-balancer

I have two nifi nodes I want to run behind an AWS Application Load Balancer.  This type of load balancer decrypts the incoming request to parse it, then re-encrypts with it's own cert.

I'm having issues getting the Nifi to recognize the user making a request since the requests always come in with the LB cert instead of the original users cert.  I'm wondering if Nifi already has a means of handling this, for instance is it possible to have my LB set a header to specify the DN of the user's cert and have nifi authenticate first the LB DN and, if that passes, the header?

I am aware that the other two types of load balancers provided by AWS would in theory work, so long as I updated the SAN of the nifi certs to include the LB DN.  However, I have reasons I would prefer to stick to an ALB.  Is their any viable manner to properly authenticate users behind an ALB?

Answer (score 0):

The Proxy Configuration section of the Admin Guide should cover this:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration

Specifically the part about X-ProxiedEntitiesChain.